# Perl matrix to hash conversion

Tags: perl, hash, matrix

I'm trying to convert a big matrix (a tab separated file with different number of elements in each column) into a hash of arrays. In the first step, I succesfully load the file and using Test::CSV convert the columns of the data into lists, but in doing so, I noted that the length of each list is the number of elements corresponding to the larger column, i.e. for those columns with fewer elements, a blank space is present. This is my code so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
    sep_char => "\t",
});

open( LIST, "<", "testfile" ) or die "No esta el archivo\n";

while (<LIST>) {
     if ($csv->parse($_)) {
    my   @columns = $csv->fields();
        print "$columns[0]\t$columns[1]\t$columns[2]","\n";
    } else {
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
    }
}
close(LIST);
```

The input matrix has 20 columns and between 4500-8500 rows plus a header row (which ideally I would like to use as keys in the hash). For simplicity I build a "testfile" with three columns, no header and different number of elements (in the same format as the original input file). Here is the content of testfile:

```
1 1 2
2 2
  3 4
5 6
6 7
7 8 8
8 9
```

This is the output. I presume that the "Use of uninitializated value..." is related to the blank spaces.

```
1  1  2
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at blast.cruce.especies.pl line 16, <LIST> line 3.
2  2  
  3  4
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at blast.cruce.especies.pl line 16, <LIST> line 5.
5  6  
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at blast.cruce.especies.pl line 16, <LIST> line 6.
6  7  
7  8  8
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at blast.cruce.especies.pl line 16, <LIST> line 8.
8  9  
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at blast.cruce.especies.pl line 16, <LIST> line 9.
Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at blast.cruce.especies.pl line 16, <LIST> line 9.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason you're seeing those errors is you're pulling in lines similar to:

```
\t\t1
```

Which parses to the list:

```
( undef, undef, 1 )
```

Since you're pulling in a 0 width character to the field. The problem isn't the parsing, it's the printing. If you want to examine the contents after parsing use Data::Printer or Data::Dumper to format the line for output, which won't give you the errors where the undef values are interpolated.

Edit: Your code is correct:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV;

my $csv = Text::CSV->new({
  sep_char => ",",
  });

while (<DATA>) {
        if ($csv->parse($_)) {
    my   @columns = $csv->fields();
          print "$columns[0]\t$columns[1]\t$columns[2]","\n";
          } else {
        my $err = $csv->error_input;
    }
}


__DATA__
1,1,2
2,2,
,3,4
5,6,
6,7,
7,8,8
8,9,
```

prints:

```
C:\>perl testcsv.pl
1       1       2
2       2
        3       4
5       6
6       7
7       8       8
8       9
```

(The changes are only to read from the DATA handle instead of a file.)

Comment: Hi Oesor. Im still dont try the Data::Printer or Dumper, but I change the tab separator in testfile for commas and change the sep_char to "," and now I cant print the matrix equal to the input.

Comment: I edited my post to show that your code does work properly with comma separators.

Comment: Nice edit. Just for reference, you have to make sure you have a comma at the end of the lines such as `6,7,`. Otherwise `@columns` will only have 2 elements and `$columns[2]` will be undefined and you'll get the same error..

Comment: Thanks Oesor for your help. Your mention to the \t\t1 pulling open my eyes.

Answer (score 0):

here again with some issues. I simplify the above code to this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;
use Text::CSV;
use Data::Dumper;
$Data::Dumper::Indent=0;

my @columns;
my %matrixhash;
my $csv = Text::CSV->new( { sep_char => "," } );

open( LIST, "<", "testfile.csv" ) or die "No esta el archivo\n";

while (<LIST>) {
    if ( $csv->parse($_) ) {
        @columns = $csv->fields();

%matrixhash=(
    a=>$columns[0],
    b=>$columns[1],
    c=>$columns[2]
);
}   
        print Dumper \@columns;
        print "\n";

}
print "Printing Hash: ",Dumper \%matrixhash;
close(LIST);
```

The output is:

```
$VAR1 = ['1','1','2'];
$VAR1 = ['2','2',''];
$VAR1 = ['','3','4'];
$VAR1 = ['5','6',''];
$VAR1 = ['6','7',''];
$VAR1 = ['7','8','8'];
$VAR1 = ['8','9',''];
$VAR1 = {'c' => '','a' => '8','b' => '9'};
```

which correspond to the lines of my matrix and the hash indeed is the last line. In order to continue my donwstream analysis I need a collection of hashes which contain the column header as keys and the columns information from the matrix as values and of course without the blanks. For example, for the first column of the matrix, the hash will be: a=> {1,2,5,6,7,8). So, my second thought was, what happens if I transpose the matrix?:

```
$VAR1 = ['1','2','','5','6','7','8'];
$VAR1 = ['1','2','3','6','7','8','9'];
$VAR1 = ['2','','4','','','8',''];
Printing Hash: $VAR1 = {'c' => '4','a' => '2','b' => ''}
```

This is more close to my need, but still have the hash problem. And of course probably I will need transpose the matrix previous in the code (the example was handly transposed).

Again, all help is welcome.
Christian.

Comment: You should ask a new question as a new question, not the answer to the previous one. You're looking for something along the lines of `if (defined $columns[0]) { push @{$matrixhash{a}}, $columns[0] }`, though, which will create a hash value containing an arrayref similar to {a => [1, 2, 5, 6, 7, 8] }

Comment: Oh. I dont see the question as new question, because the initial problem ("I'm trying to convert a big matrix (a tab separated file with different number of elements in each column into a hash of arrays") is still present. But your rigth, from script perspective is a new question. My mistake. I will follow your indication and also publish as new question. Thanks.